# How to compile opusfile or opustools?

Tags: linux, opus

when I compile opusfile-0.12, it show me that, so how can i solve the compile error? anyone konw??please help!!!

```
[root@vm7 opusfile-0.12]# make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/opusfile-0.12'
  CCLD     examples/opusfile_example
./.libs/libopusurl.so: undefined reference to `BIO_meth_set_read'
./.libs/libopusurl.so: undefined reference to `BIO_meth_set_write'
./.libs/libopusurl.so: undefined reference to `BIO_meth_set_ctrl'
./.libs/libopusurl.so: undefined reference to `BIO_meth_set_create'
./.libs/libopusurl.so: undefined reference to `BIO_meth_set_puts'
./.libs/libopusurl.so: undefined reference to `BIO_meth_free'
./.libs/libopusurl.so: undefined reference to `BIO_meth_new'
./.libs/libopusurl.so: undefined reference to `BIO_set_init'
./.libs/libopusurl.so: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
./.libs/libopusurl.so: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
./.libs/libopusurl.so: undefined reference to `BIO_meth_set_destroy'
./.libs/libopusurl.so: undefined reference to `BIO_set_data'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [examples/opusfile_example] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/opusfile-0.12'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Fedora 35 example : No errors with gcc-11 or gcc-8.2 ...... I.e. `cd opusfile-0.12/ && ./configure && make` → The ten "libopus" files were created. ......... Please edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69998440/edit to include OS name and version.